# Aligning equations - System of equations all numbered

Tags: equations, align

I tried to write a system of equations with all equations numerated, but they are not aligned:

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
R_a = R_d\\ 
\frac{dq(t)}{dt} = ir - r_d(t) \\ 
q(0)=0 \\
r_d(t) = TTR(t) R_d
\end{empheq}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: alignment points in `align` are marked by `&` usually just before an `=`

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle can you show me how please? I tried also with &, my result is bad.

Comment: make a proper test file that shows the problem and can be run, and someone will no doubt show how to fix it

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle I solved placing & before each equation.

Comment: Aligning on = is more conventional (if you put `&` before each equation you are marking up each row as just having a right hand side but no left hand term in the equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Mark alignment points with `&` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
R_a &= R_d\\ 
\frac{dq(t)}{dt} &= ir - r_d(t) \\ 
q(0)&=0 \\
r_d(t) &= TTR(t) R_d
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good @DavidCarlisle!