# Aligning equations - modifying code

Tags: equations, align

I'd like to maintain my code's structure and align the equations (vertical alignment of = symbols). Is it possible?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
r_d(t) = k \hspace{0.1cm} q(t)\\
R_d = k \hspace{0.1cm} Q
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for your time.

EDIT: this question differs from [Aligning equations - System of equations all numbered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404260/aligning-equations-system-of-equations-all-numbered) because here the equations are not numered and here I don't use \usepackage{empheq}.

Comment: Hello @Zarko this is not a duplicate because here the code is different.

Comment: It's perfect not a perfect duplicate since here one needs to change the argument of array to `{rcl} `in addition to putting `&` sings before and after the `=` signs, but using `cases` might be better anyway.

Comment: you gave _again_ not provided a proper complete example. the align syntax is amsmath unrelated to empheq so this is simply a duplicate of your earlier question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what did I forget in my question?

Comment: look at my answer to your last question, it starts `\documentclass` and ends `\end{document}` and loads all packages needed to run. Your fraagment doesn't do any of those things you were lucky I could guess the `empheq` package was used as you hadn't mentioned it anywhere. similarly your markup here requires amsmath but you don't mention that

Answer (score 6):

Use the `empheq` environment (from the homonymous package – needless to load `amsmath` nor `mathtools`: empheq does it):

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
r_d(t) &= k \, q(t)\\
R_d &= k \, Q
\end{empheq}
```

Comment: Your solution is excellent @Bernard

Answer (score 4):

The code should be

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}% for the left brace
\begin{aligned}% for alignment at =
r_d(t) &= k q(t)\\
R_d    &= k Q
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

There's no reason for the `\hspace{0.1cm}`: multiplication is denoted by simple juxtaposition.

Comment: I like it @egreg

Comment: Event if I risk to start a religious war (of course I'm kidding) I personally put `\,` in order to indicate multiplication, like in @Bernard 's answer. This question is a perfect example for why several TeX users are doing this: in `k\,q(t)` it is immediately clear that k multiplies the function q(t), and not, say, k multiplies q, which multiplies t, which for some reasons is in brackets. So even if you don't like this practice, nevertheless people using it are not necessarily "wrong".

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to preserve the use of `equation*` and `array` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'equation*' env.

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\{ \begin{array}{@{} r @{{}={}} l }
r_d(t) & k\,q(t)\\
R_d    & k\,Q
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```